# How to show Installed Programs in a specific user in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm on Windows 7 and I'd like to disable an account but would like to see if/what programs are installed for that user only ans not for all users.

And if I disable that account, what happens to those programs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you start up a program that wants a user you have disabled, then it will just set it up again. Very straightforward and nothing to be overly concerned with. It is just like running the program in a new user.

Answer (score 1):

As almost all applications install entries in the Start menu, the simplest way
to find out which products are installed by a certain user is to look at his
Start menu.

Use Windows Explorer to go to the user Startup folder at
`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.

You will find there all the installed entries of the user named `USER`.

If you wish to make these products universally available, you could most simply
copy these entries to your own Startup folder or to All Users at
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`.

Note that when uninstalling a product whose Startup entry was copied or moved,
the product's uninstallation will not find and delete it.
You should use in this case an uninstaller like
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/).